# How can I remove the application name from a Grails application’s URL?

Tags: url, tomcat, grails, tomcat6, grails-2.0

I have an application running at a URL like this:

> http://myapp.mydomain.com/myapp

I don’t want the `/myapp` part in the URL. So how can I get rid of the application name? I want just

> http://myapp.mydomain.com

to be the URL. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

bit detailed approach

**First Method:**

> first shutdown your tomcat [from the bin directory (`sh shutdown.sh`)] then you
>   must delete all the content of your tomcat webapps folder (`rm -fr *`) then 
>   rename your WAR file to `ROOT.war` finally start your tomcat
>   [from the bin directory (`sh startup.sh`)]

**Second Method:**

> leave your war file in `CATALINA_BASE/webapps`, under its original name - turn off 
>   autoDeploy and deployOnStartup in your Host element in the server.xml file.
>   explicitly define all application Contexts in server.xml, specifying both path 
>   and docBase. You must do this, because you have disabled all the Tomcat 
>   auto-deploy mechanisms, and Tomcat will not deploy your applications anymore
>   unless it finds their Context in the server.xml.

**Note:**

> that this last method also implies that in order to make any change to any
>   application, you will have to stop and restart Tomcat.

**Third Method:**

> Place your war file outside of `CATALINA_BASE/webapps` (it must be outside 
>   to prevent double deployment). - Place a context file named `ROOT.xml` in
>   `CATALINA_BASE/conf//`. The single element in this context file MUST have a 
>   docBase attribute pointing to the location of your war file. The path element 
>   should not be set - it is derived from the name of the .xml file, in this 
>   case `ROOT.xml`. See the Context Container above for details.

Comment: Method 3: the `ROOT.xml` needs to go in `CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost` (technically it's `conf/<Engine name>/<Host name>`, but `Catalina` and `localhost` are the defaults in the out-of-the-box `server.xml`) not directly in `conf`.

Comment: I tried the first method, Most of the time "http://myapp.mydomain.com" gives me bad request error, If i access the app by IP, Its working fine. What is the solution for this. I am using tomcat 6.

Answer (score 3):

1) Your app server needs to be configured to have your grails application as ROOT application

2) your grails application context path should be "/" or app.context=/

Comment: what's your environment anyway ?

Comment: My environment is production, Its not working, I have created the war file using "grails prod war".

Comment: How to do the first one " app server needs to be configured to have your grails application as ROOT application".  I have done the second one

Comment: to be specific, which app server are you deploying your app to ? or is it cloud deployed like GAE ??

Comment: its tomcat6 server deployed in cloud

Comment: you can make the current application as your Root Application in Tomcat [Reference](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application_.3F)

Answer (score 1):

You can make Tomcat serve a webapp as the root context by simply naming it `ROOT.war`, i.e. take the `myapp-0.1.war` generated by Grails and copy it to `TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/ROOT.war`.

If you have a setting for `grails.serverURL` in your `Config.groovy` you will need to override this for your production environment to ensure that any absolute links generated by Grails are correct

```
environments {
  production {
    grails.serverURL = 'http://myapp.mydomain.com'
  }
}
```

But in Grails 2 it is usually safe to omit `grails.serverURL` entirely and let the app deduce the right value at runtime.  You only need it if you're running behind a reverse proxy that doesn't pass through the correct `Host` header.