# How to configure apache tomcat to point to my project?

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I have apache tomcat running into a specific server and I've deployed a project named where2go. So I have a file named:

where2go.war and I deployed this one.
Right now when I try to access this link:

where2go.ca is going to no where and you get a blank page.

If I want to access the project I need to go to:

where2go.ca/where2go

How do I configure my server to show where2go project when I access where2go.ca?

Comment: In web.xml. Surely you've already done that?

Comment: Didn't modified the web.xml. What exactly do I need to change there? I saw there is this: "servlet-mapping" tag pointing to "/". It's the project under the root folder, right? But when I deploy where2go it's not on root... it's into /where2go folder.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right your question, you want to put your project on the root of the server and call it like the following: `where2go.ca/` instead of `where2go.ca/where2go/`

If so, in order to achieve that, you need to modify your `server.xml` (you can find it in the tomcat configuration folder.

Open the server.xml file using your favorite text editor, and add the following directive the file, before the `</Engine>` directive

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context path="" docBase="where2go" reloadable="true" override="true"></Context>
</Host>
```

The above will change your server root path to your project folder.
This change is good when you don't have other project deployed on the same server.

Another solution (to my opinion less preferable) is to manually deploy your project into the ROOT folder inside your `/webapps` folder.

Hope it will help,

Liron

Comment: I made the change you said. It kind of worked, but not entirely... I was able to access the project accessing where2go.ca, but it got really really slow. Also I saw that I was able to access also where2go.ca/where2go... so seems that I had 2 instances of the application running... Tonight I'll try to undeploy the where2go application and see if it works properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After looking a while I found the solution on this link:

[How can I remove the application name from a Grails application’s URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257130/how-can-i-remove-the-application-name-from-a-grails-application-s-url)

I used the first method:

**first shutdown your tomcat [from the bin directory (sh shutdown.sh)] then you must delete all the content of your tomcat webapps folder (rm -fr *) then rename your WAR file to ROOT.war finally start your tomcat [from the bin directory (sh startup.sh)]**